# Grub problem with password

Tags: boot, grub2, password

Accidently my notebook after upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 19.10 got stuck on Ubuntu logo. I read some threads and I already know what to do. But since I use special symbols in my password, I don't know how to type my password in *GRUB* -> *Advanced* -> *root*. It tells me `give root pass` and I don't know how. So is <kbd>NumLock</kbd> enabled? How can I type *@* or *&*? How do I type numbers?

Comment: What type of keyboard do you have?

Comment: Exactly this one https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0810/3669/files/czech-windows-keyboard-layout-keyshorts_1024x1024.png?3916

Comment: for numbers, use **Shift** + **+** (1 for example), and for &/@, use **AltGr** + **C** / **V**

Comment: Thanks alot wise man!

Comment: Is it a solution of your issue? If it is, I will write an answer